# web app with local db .mdf file how to publish to Azure

Tags: azure, publish

I have a web app published on Azure.(created locally via visual studio)
I ve also migrated my main Database(Azure Sql database) and connected with the web app and of cource already created an sql server instance.
My problem is with my local db file .mdf file in my App_Data folder.
When i published my app  returned error below:
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a LocalDB installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the LocalDB feature is enabled.
How to attach .mdf file ? and associated it with my sql server instance?
Thanks

Comment: You need to upload full .bak. You cant only restore .mdf file as it wont work. Please kindly test it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use SQL Server Express (pretty sure there is no Express installed). Why do you want to use SQL Server Express?

Anyway, you can migrate it to Azure into SQL Server Compact - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-sql-server-compact-databases-2-of-12

But that way is not very efficient if you plan to implement any type of replication - any instance will have own db - and some other drawbacks.

I believe that the best way here is to use SQL Azure and migrate your data into it if there is no need in something like SQL Server Compact/Express.